# Excel VBA read-only status explanation when a workbook set to this value

Tags: excel, client-server, vba

I want to make sure that affecting a file with this value is for the other users attempting to write inside the file.

My aim is to prevent my file (as a Server file) to be written by others on Windows Server whereas the Client file XLSM is using this Server file.

Is that correct ? Right now I'm developping the Macros application in stand-alone mode at home office. I cannot test the interaction with other users.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a file as Read-only in the operating system then it cannot be changed by any user. If you open a file then it is read-only to any other user, unless filesharing is explicitly enabled. If you open a file Read Only (by using code like

```
  Set wb = Workbooks.open(Filename:=myfile, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Then it is set to read-only for that user. None of this will prevent the user who opened it read-only from saving a copy of the file under a different name.

Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: I want to be clearer and reformulate how I understand the answer. By the way I use the Set statement as you write it.
I want to prevent any other users to write the file whereas I use it by setting Read-only status.
When setting Read Write, I want to be exclusive to write in the file whereas none user could write inside it.
In both cases, the other users can only read the opened file.

Comment: You could examine the current login name as part of an IF statement and open the file as read only if the name isn't yours. The function (Environ$("Username")) returns the current user

Comment: I know the function but is there a way to fetch the "reader" that have opened the file ?
Thanks;